# Firebase Android - Update child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm stuck at this point a long time now and i know, there are a lot of other questions like mine, but nothing helped me.

So, i only want to update the child value (picture). I'm struggling with the ID given from Firebase.  Here I'm using this:

```
DatabaseReference updateData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userInfos").child(user.getUid();
```

after that:

```
updateData.child("vorname").setValue(vName);
```

But i keep getting a new ID under "userInfos".

Are there any suggestions?

Thanks

[image: Picture]

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: That's not what, I was refering to. Still the same problem. I need to get into the Uid to change the value. Not pushing a new Node into my userInfos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is not specific, what is user.getUid(). Do you get it from firebase auth or it's a push id generated by firebase database.

```
DatabaseReference updateData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
.getReference("userInfos")
.child(user_id_will_be included_here);
```

Then

```
updateData.child("vorname").setValue(vName);
```

will work fine. But it is better practice to use auth id as userId in database. It helps to retrive user data in future. You can get that id easily

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
.getCurrentUser() ;
Toast.makeText(this, "" + currentFirebaseUser.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: ahaaaa! That worked just fine. Thanks a lot! PS.: user was/is FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();